# Making code signing token credentials persistent

Tags: windows, code-signing-certificate

I have a commercial code-signing certificate, which was delivered on a USB token. The vendor (GlobalSign) provides a download to a utility that needs to be installed to use the token, [SafeNet](https://safenet.gemalto.com/multi-factor-authentication/security-applications/authentication-client-token-management/).

This all works fine; however, I've previously had the ability for the password to persist for a period of time - meaning the first use of the day would require the password, but subsequent uses within the period (4 hours) wouldn't need me to reauthenticate.

This was the case until I had to rebuild the OS a few months ago, a completely fresh install of Windows 10. Since then, I've had to enter the password each and every time I sign something, regardless of whether that's via Visual Studio or `signtool`:

[image]

despite the settings in the SafeNet client being set to "Enable Single Login"

[image]

I'm fairly certain that my previous environment displayed a SafeNet-style authentication dialog rather than a Windows Security one. It's more of an inconvenience than anything, but is there something I can set/change/install to force SafeNet to do the authentication rather than Windows, which might restore the ability to remember the password for a period of time?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I've finally been able to resolve this issue by updating the Safenet client to the current latest version, `10.7.167.0`. After installation, the Windows "Smart Card" authentication screen is replaced with the Safenet equivalent, and credential persistence is enforced as per the settings.

Answer (score -2):

One thing You can do is write an automation .Net exe which keeps running in background and whenever this screen prompts it will enter password automatically and clicks on OK.